# What packages do I need for Arch Linux to use Wi-Fi?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I've read Arch wiki for installation but not really sure what packages I need in order to use Wi-Fi after re-boot the system.

In the wiki, it is said [In the installation image, systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved, iwd and ModemManager are preconfigured and enabled by default. That will not be the case for the installed system.].

I'm planning to install "networkmanager" and enable it by commands "systemctl enable NetworkManager".

Do I need the above-mentioned packages when installing the system? or dhcp?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `iwd` or `wpa_supplicant` installed, you can connect to wifi from the command line using `iwctl` , `wpa_cli` or the configuration file.

[Iwd on archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/iwd)

[Wpasupplicant on archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wpa_supplicant)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use "iwd" and see whether I can use Wi-Fi after reboot.